# How to find the number of qualified people per job SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

What I am trying to do is get the number of qualified people per job.

A person is qualified for a job if they have all the skills a job requires.

Tables:

**Job(job_code, job_name)**

**Job_skill(job_code, s_code)**

**Skills(s_code, skill_name)**

**Person(per_id, email)**

**Person_skill(per_id, s_code)**

I’ve been stuck on using the minus as such in the following pseudocode:

```
For each job
From a table of jobs and persons
    Where not exits
        For each person
            Get jobs of each person

            Minus   

            Get the skills of job

        Remove appropriate person
```

But, I feel this logic is incorrect and may be going down the wrong path entirely.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is need for a loop:

Given this setup:

```
create table Job(job_code varchar(10), job_name varchar(100));

insert into job values ('dev', 'Developer');
insert into job values ('mgr', 'Manager');
insert into job values ('designer', 'WebDesigner');

create table Job_skill(job_code varchar(10), s_code varchar(10));
insert into job_skill values ('dev', 'sql');
insert into job_skill values ('dev', 'java');
insert into job_skill values ('dev', 'oop');
insert into job_skill values ('mgr', 'ppt');
insert into job_skill values ('mgr', 'outlook');
insert into job_skill values ('designer', 'html');
insert into job_skill values ('designer', 'css');
insert into job_skill values ('designer', 'graphics');

create table Person(per_id integer, name varchar(254));
insert into person values (1, 'Arthur');
insert into person values (2, 'Zaphod');
insert into person values (3, 'Tricia');
insert into person values (4, 'Ford');

create table Person_skill(per_id integer, s_code varchar(10));

insert into person_skill values (1, 'sql');
insert into person_skill values (1, 'java');
insert into person_skill values (1, 'oop');

insert into person_skill values (2, 'ppt');

insert into person_skill values (3, 'html');
insert into person_skill values (3, 'css');
insert into person_skill values (3, 'graphics');

insert into person_skill values (4, 'ppt');
insert into person_skill values (4, 'outlook');
```

Arthur is qualified as a Developer, Tricia as a WebDesigner and Ford as a Manager. Zaphod can only use outlook so he lacks the PowerPoint skills to be a manager.

The following query shows that for each person:

```
with skill_count as (
  select ps.per_id,
         js.job_code, 
         count(js.s_code) as num_skills
  from person_skill ps
    join job_skill js on ps.s_code = js.s_code
  group by ps.per_id, js.job_code  
  order by ps.per_id
), required_skills as (
  select job_code, count(*) as num_required
  from job_skill 
  group by job_code
)
select p.name, 
       sc.job_code, 
       case 
         when sc.num_skills = rs.num_required then 'qualified'
         else 'not qualified'
       end as status
from skill_count sc
  join required_skills rs on sc.job_code = rs.job_code
  join person p on sc.per_id = p.per_id
order by p.name;
```

The result based on the sample data is:

```
name   | job_code | status       
-------+----------+--------------
Arthur | dev      | qualified    
Ford   | mgr      | qualified    
Tricia | designer | qualified    
Zaphod | mgr      | not qualified
```